Selection rule in three dimensional harmonic oscillator in representation $(n,l,m)$
Selection rule for transition probability of first order perturbation . I don't understand why the selection rule $$\langle l'm'n'|x|l,m,n \rangle =\delta_{m'm} \delta_{n'n} \langle l'|x|l \rangle$$ in the representation $(l,m,n)$. It's written that $'l$ is the quantum number for the component oscillator along the $x$-axis', which I don't see it clearly. My thought is to transform the bra and the ket back to the $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ representation where I can apply the $x$ as a combination of $a_{x}$ and $a_{x}^{\dagger}$. But I don't see how the result is given in $(l,m,n)$ representation as above. Thanks in advance if someone tell me how I can evaluate the ingtegral in such a elegant way!!

In your problem you have three quantum numbers (I may be using another convention but bear with). $n$ which is related to the specifics of your central potential (in this case a harmonic oscillator) and $l$ and $m$ which are angular momentum quantum numbers. These arise because your question has a central force and thus angular momentum is a conserved quantity and angular momentum quantum numbers are good. It is usually the case that $l$ corresponds to the total angular momentum magnitude and $m$ corresponds to the component of the angular momentum in a specific direction (usually $z$).
As you have noticed you need to calculate that inner product for the selection rules and inner products in functional spaces are essentially integrals. We also have a position operator ($x$) in there. Now it would be very beneficial for us to work in the position basis since position operators become very simple to deal with. In this basis position operators just multiply. Therefore, our problem at hand is to find use the wavefunctions in the position basis to solve an integral.
$\langle x,y,z|n,l,m \rangle = \Psi_{n,l,m}(x,y,z) $
$ACos(wt) \langle n',l',m'|\hat{x}|n,l,m \rangle = ACos(wt)\int{\Psi^*_{n',l',m'}(x,y,z)x\Psi_{n,l,m}(x,y,z) \,dxdydz}$
Now here you suggested to expand your state in terms of cartesian coordinates, however as I'll show in a moment it is actually much easier to use spherical polar coordinates and instead turn the positon operator in the x direction from cartesian to polar coordinates as $x=rsin(\theta)cos(\phi)$. Therefore the integral we really have to solve looks like:
$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\Psi^*_{n',l',m'}(r,\theta,\phi)\Psi_{n,l,m}(r,\theta,\phi)r^3sin^2(\theta)cos(\phi)\,drd\theta d\phi$
(don't forget the jacobian)
Ok but what are the energy eigenfunctions in the position basis? Thankfully due to the symmetries in our problem (Namely the seperabiltiy of the Hamiltonian, in the radial and angular directions). Our energy eigenfunction is actually the product of some function of r and some function of $\theta , \phi$
$\Psi_{n,l,m}(r,\theta,\phi) = R_{n,l,m}(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$
Since our problem only has a central force, this must mean that our hamiltonian had an isolated radial operator and an angular momentum operator which acts only on this $Y_l^m$ part of the function. Therefore, those $Y_l^m$ functions must be angular momentum eigenfunctions for our overall state to satisfy the TISE, and indeed they are. In other words they are the Spherical Harmonics. So since we know what half of the wavefunction is we can start doing some integrals.
$\int_0^{\infty}r^3R^*_{n',l',m'}(r)R_{n,l,m}(r)\,dr\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}{Y_{l'}^{m'^*}(\theta ,\phi)Y_l^m(\theta ,\phi)sin^2(\theta)cos(\phi)d\theta d\phi}$
I'll leave doing these integrals to you and if you spot some symmetries you will actually see that for most n,l,m values these go to zero. However, most of these integrals are very painful and there are a lot of them. In fact the method I have shown you here is perhaps the worst one for finding selection rules. There are more elegant ones involving angular momentum conservation arguments or some smart commutator algebra but I will leave those for another answer for now.

Thanks a lot!! Yes, this is the standard way to solve such problem. As you said, it's painful to do the calculation and I think the solution given, which I stated in the beginning is neat and elegant. What I want to know is what properties are used to reach such a result. Actually I've encountered some other questions about the selection rule involving these integrals of spherical harmonics. They just gives out the elegant result without illustrating where they come from.

@GeneVettel the property is the stationary state eigenvectors and eigenvalues in $H\Psi = E\Psi$ that can find all those $n,l,m$ solutions. It is quite hard to believe at first as linear algebra methods sometimes feel too powerful as almost magical.

"Separation of variables" gives another explanation where this comes from, by exploiting symmetry. In the original Schröinger equation of a moving particle, if the potential depends only on the space variable, hence is independent of the other (time) variable, separation of variables yields solutions of the form $\Psi(x,y,z,t) = e^{iat} \psi(x,y,z)$, a $t$ part times an $x,y,z$ part. In this problem the potential depends only on the radius variable, independent of the angle variables $\theta,\phi$ of spherical coordinates, and the solution breaks into an $r$ part times a $\theta,\phi$ part.

@James Yes. It pops out as a well-known conclusion. But I cann't find any steps of the derivation.

@GeneVettel numerically it's entirely linear algebra. Suppose a finite but very large 3D space volume is chopped up into very tiny grid locations. Then one can construct a giant matrix H which acts on a very long vector $\Psi$ to give a single scalar number E times of the same vector $\Psi$, i.e. $H\Psi=E\Psi$. This is a standard eigenvalue eigenvector problem in linear algebra and there are methods that can churn out all eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Those eigenvector numbers magically carve for us all the stationary shapes of $\Psi$ that are analytically described by very complex functions
